# String con valores iguales no entran en una condición

Tags: java

No entiendo por qué dos variables de tipo String que tienen valores iguales no entran en un condicional.

```
String consultaVerificar = " SELECT codigo_carta, turno, fecha FROM carta  WHERE fecha = '2017-11-26' ";

String codigoCartaObtenida;
String turnoCartaObtenida = "";
String fechaCartaObtenida = "";

String fechaCampo = campoFecha.getText();
String turnoCampo = comboBoxTurno.getSelectedItem().toString();

Connection con = new ConexionBD().conectarBD();
Statement sta = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(consultaVerificar);
while (rs.next()) {

    codigoCartaObtenida = rs.getString("codigo_carta");
    turnoCartaObtenida = rs.getString("turno");
    fechaCartaObtenida = rs.getString("fecha");

}
 /*solo Para ver los valores */

System.out.println("el valor de la variable *turnoCartaObtenida*   es : "+turnoCartaObtenida);
System.out.println("el valor de la variable  *fechaCartaObtenida*   es : "+fechaCartaObtenida);
System.out.println("el valor de la variable *turnoCampo*  es :  "+turnoCampo);

if (turnoCartaObtenida.equals(turnoCampo)) {
    System.out.println("si son iguales ");
}
```

- El valor de la variable `turnoCartaObtenida`   es  `Mañana`
- El valor de la variable  `fechaCartaObtenida`   es `2017-11-26`
- El valor de la variable `turnoCampo`  es  `Mañana`

Comment: podrías indicarnos que te pintan estas lineas:     System.out.println("el valor de turno obtenido es "+turnoCartaObtenida);
            System.out.println("el valor de fecha  obtenido es "+fechaCartaObtenida);

Comment: Gracias por responder y bueno lo que me imprimen esas lineas son estos resultados :  el   valor de turno obtenido es Mañana ...
                    el valor de fecha  obtenido es 2017-11-26..
                    el valor del combo es Mañana....

Comment: y lo que no entiendo es porque si los valores de las  variables  turnoCartaObtenida y  turnoCampo son iguales no me entran en la condicion

Comment: oh ok, cual es el valor de turno Campo, puedes poner lo que te imprime en tu pregunta para que sea más legible

Comment: ok ya vi, puedes indicar como cargas tu combobox ?

Comment: Te refieres a los valores del comboBox , si es asi yo  los cargo asi  : comboBoxTurno.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Mañana", "Tarde", "Noche" }));

Comment: prueba la solución que puse abajo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según los comentarios, al parecer los valores son iguales, pero puede ser que uno de ellos tenga espacios en blanco adelante o atrás.

Para solucionar ese problema te recomiendo que hagas un `trim` a cada String antes de la comparación, y también podrías usar el método `equalsIgnoreCase` para que no haga caso a las mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Prueba esto:

```
if (turnoCartaObtenida.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(turnoCampo.trim())) {
    System.out.println("si son iguales ");
}
```

Comment: :) ey Si funciono,  eso era el problema los espacios , muchas gracias eh :) ..ahora si puedo continuar :)

Comment: no hay problema :) , si puedes marca la pregunta como resuelta :)

Comment: @SoftPanG Aparte de haber resuelto tu problema a nivel de código, considera **ir a la raíz del problema** y corregir los datos también allí. Viendo que los valores provienen de una base de datos, conviene que revises dichos valores, mediante consultas de actualización adecuadas que eliminen en los datos los espacios de más que a veces hay al principio o al final de las palabras, los dobles espacios en blanco, etc.

Comment: A pesar de resolver su problema, no marca la solución como aceptada :(

Comment: @diegodeveloper amigo gracias por tu gran ayuda :) , me habia olvidado de marcarla como aceptada :(